# different outputs from a simple string format call

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

On my windows machine running Visual Studio 2019, when I convert a decimal to a string:

```
decimal n = 200;
var s = n.ToString("P0");
```

... I get: `200%`. (no space)

However when I do this on my Mac in VsCode, I get `200 %` (with a space).

This is causing some unit tests to fail. What's the best way to get consistent behavior for the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

When number gets converted into string, the platform in your case takes the current system culture into consideration. To make it consistent you may use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
decimal number = 2;
var result = number.ToString("P0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```